# How to rename columns in R

Tags: r, rename, rank

This is quite rudimentary but the examples that I am finding are more complex. The code below is what I am using

```
    con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),"Database 1")
    top20empdb<- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT 
    area,name,cityP,Primnaics,busdesc,privgovsta,empsizval,empsizrng,releaseno FROM empdb where 
    releaseno = '211'")
    dbDisconnect(con)
```

First, I need the column cityP to be renamed City and empsizrng to be renamed as Employment Range. Next (and this may be another question) is to have them only produce the top 20 by empsizval. Would the top or bottom commands be needed here and if so, does it come after the select or inside of it?

Comment: you need empsizval by area or name? What do you want it to be grouped by?

Comment: @KarthikS, Yes. So the end product will be the top 20 (ranked by empsizval) for each area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is an option with `tidyverse`, where we `rename` the columns and get the top 20 rows by using `top_n` with `wt` as 'empsizval'

```
library(dplyr)
out <- top20empdb %>%
        rename(cityP = City, EmploymentRange = empsizrng) %>%
        group_by(area) %>%
        top_n(20, wt = empsizval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
names(top20empdb)[names(top20empdb)=='cityP'] <- 'City'
names(top20empdb)[names(top20empdb)=='empsizrng'] <- 'EmploymentRange'
```

For your next query:

```
top20empdb %>% group_by(area) %>% slice_max(order_by = EmploymentRange, n = 20)
```

Grouping by area and fetching top 10 EmploymentRange values.